# Import and update several CSV files automatically into Excel workbook

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

I have a folder containing multiple CSV files and I have another folder containing an Excel workbook. I want to import all the CSV files from the workbook by the click of a button into seperate sheets (fx 3.csv will have sheetname "3" etc.). These CSV files are updated frequently, however not always on the same day. I want the import code to also update whatever CSV files have been updated. I assume that this is implicitly done every time I import all the files.

The following code does the trick..well almost. The problem is whenever I click on the button it doesn't overwrite the existing sheets. It adds new sheets. Let's say I upload (for the very first time). The sheets inside the workbook are called city1.csv, city2.csv etc.. The second time I run the code, it has added another range of sheets city1, city2 etc. The third time city1(1), city2(2) etc.

How can I make the import code to overwrite every time I click on the button instead of adding new sheets?

Thx!

```
Sub import_test3()
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim FilesInPath As String
 Dim MyFiles() As String
 Dim SourceRcount As Long
 Dim Fnum As Long
 Dim mybook As Workbook
 Dim basebook As Workbook

 MyPath = "\\filepath\folder"

 If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
 MyPath = MyPath & "\"
 End If

 FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")
 If FilesInPath = "" Then
 MsgBox "No CSV files found"
 Exit Sub
 End If

 On Error GoTo CleanUp

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

 Fnum = 0
 Do While FilesInPath <> ""
 Fnum = Fnum + 1
 ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
 MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
 FilesInPath = Dir()
 Loop

 If Fnum > 0 Then
 For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
 Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
 mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:= _
 basebook.Sheets(basebook.Sheets.Count)

 On Error Resume Next
 ActiveSheet.Name = mybook.Name
 On Error GoTo 0


 mybook.Close savechanges:=False
 Next Fnum
 End If
 CleanUp:
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 parts to this solution: finding out if a sheet exists and overwriting it; and finding out if a file has changed.
Your issue with the first point is that you don't really have anything to query whether the sheet exists or not.  You can find the name that the worksheet would have using:

```
Dim sheetName as String
sheetName = Left(MyFiles(Fnum), InStr(MyFiles(Fnum), ".") - 1)
```

You can then loop through all you sheets to see if that exists already:

```
Dim sheetExists As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetCounter As Integer
sheetExists = False
sheetCounter = 0
For Each ws In basebook.Worksheets
    sheetCounter = sheetCounter + 1
    If ws.Name = sheetName Then
        sheetExists = True
    End If
Next ws
```

Notice the `sheetCounter` variable.  This lets us track where the existing sheet is so we can push the new version into the same spot in `Sheets`.

Next we can open our new workbook and assign it to the `mybook` reference.  If the sheet already exists we should delete it and if it doesn't exist we want to put the new sheet to the back the `Sheets` Collection.

```
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
If sheetExists Then
    basebook.Sheets(sheetName).Delete
Else
    sheetCounter = basebook.Sheets.Count
End If
mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:= basebook.Sheets(sheetCounter)
```

Then we go ahead and copy the sheet into the existing workbook, rename the new sheet and close without saving:

```
basebook.Sheets(sheetCounter).Name = mybook.Name
mybook.Close savechanges:=False
```

All of the above should only happen if the `.csv` file has been modified since the workbook was last modified.  This is a bit tricky to figure out using strings as paths to files but is much more straightforward if you use `FileSystemObject`s.
`FileSystemObject`s behave like the windows folder heirarchy and provide `File` and `Folder` objects with File System properties.  Take, for example the code below:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder
Dim f As File

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Test\"

Dim lastModified As Date
lastModified = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.path)
Set fld = fso.GetFolder(path)
For Each f In fld.Files
    If f.Type = "CSV File" Then
        If f.DateLastModified - lastModified > 0 Then
            'We have a .csv file that was modified after this
            'workbook was saved so we should copy it into here 
        End If
    End If
Next f
```

This code determines the last time the workbook was saved, creates a `Folder` object based on the path to the .csv files and then cycles through each file in turn.  If the file is found to be of type `CSV File` and it has been modified since the workbook was last saved then it is of interest.

In essence, the whole routine can be combined into the following code:

```
Sub ReadUpdatedFiles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder
Dim f As File

Dim MyPath As String
MyPath = "\\filepath\folder"

Dim lastModified As Date
lastModified = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.path)

Dim sheetExists As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetName As String
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim sheetCounter As Integer

Set fld = fso.GetFolder(MyPath)
For Each f In fld.Files
    If f.Type = "CSV File" Then
        If f.DateLastModified - lastModified > 0 Then
            sheetExists = False
            sheetName = Left(f.Name, InStr(f.Name, ".") - 1)
            sheetCounter = 0
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                sheetCounter = sheetCounter + 1
                If ws.Name = sheetName Then
                    sheetExists = True
                End If
            Next ws

            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(f.path)
            If sheetExists Then
                basebook.Sheets(sheetName).Delete
            Else
                sheetCounter = basebook.Sheets.Count
            End If
            mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetCounter)
        End If
    End If
Next f

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Makes sense. Really helpful that you broke it down into steps. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider Power Query instead of VBA. Power Query is a free download for Excel 2010 and 2013, from Microsoft.

Create a query from a file, point to the CSV file and load it to a worksheet.

Rinse and repeat for each CSV file/worksheet.

Set up the data connections to refresh when the file is opened.

It is also possible to combine all CSV files into one sheet, if they have the same structure. You don't even need to know the names of the CSV files. You can load all CSV files in a specific folder and merge them into one sheet with Power Query. Mike Girvin (ExcelIsFun) has a great video about that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMQK1Zcc9jw).

Comment: #teylyn, thank you for the suggestion. Even though I've never used Power Query Before, the idea seems appealing. However, I'm restricted to download and install on my work computer. And the programme needs to work on all work computers. I would therefore prefer using VBA.

Comment: It's a simple cost/benefit analysis. Your IT department spends a few hours downloading and deploying Power Query to all users. You build the queries, everyone can consume them.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your thought, but I still prefer using VBA (despite the simple c/b analysis). Thx. I think I'm not far away from achieving my goal with the code.

Comment: I Think the problem is in the  "mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:="-part. Don't know how to let the workbook recognize existing sheets (while also being able to import the CSV files the first time)